# Should I prune this avocado tree?

Tags: pruning, avocado

I was given this Avocado tree by a friend at the beginning of May. The attached photo is from today, June 18th. How much of it, and where, should I prune it so it stays healthy? Keep in mind that I would like to plant it in the ground once I decide on the best spot, and appropriate time. Also, as you can see there is a seedling growing in the pot. When is it safe to remove it, and what is the safest way to do it? FYI, my dad says he’s concerned about the crooked trunk down at the soil line. Is that a problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the crooked trunk at soil level?

Comment: I added another picture.